# What kind of trailer hitch do i need for my Econoline 250 Extended

Tags: trailer, econoline

I have a 1990 Ford Econoline Extended ( the back is about 2 feet longer ). I want to put a hitch on the back so I can tow a small utility trailer, but I'm not sure what kind I need. Not looking for anything with too large a capacity. It looks like the back has a cross piece and two perpendicular pieces. I'm just worried that because it's an extended If i buy the ones the web suggests it wont fit., if i buy Do I need to drill  holes?

[image][image][image]

Comment: http://www.autoanything.com/towing/10A50740.aspx

Comment: Also Depending on how much tongue weight and trailer weight load that "Class" of hitch you need"